# Internet connection not working on some networks

Tags: android

I have an app that reads in an XML file, parse it and display certain elements from the xml file to the user. The problem I am having is that the network connection to the server that contains the XML file works on some networks but not on others. For example it works on my home network and the mobile 3g that comes with the phone but when I test it on the University network and the office network it cannot get a connection.

I don't understand why this is and don't know how I would fix it. I am using an HttpURLConnection to connect to the server.

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
```

urlString is the web address. I have added the permission on manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it can also server side problem..

Comment: can u access the url using a browser?

Comment: it maybe server side problem or on your network problem. Have you tested the same app in various of devices ? the same problem will occur in all the devices?

Answer (score 0):

most probably,open Internet is not available on your University /Office network or might be the url you are trying to access is blocked on these networks.

Try to browse the same url through Browser App in your phone. This will give you a better picture of the problem.